# Is a dual-body CO2 regulator worth the additional cost?

Tags: keg, co2, kegerator

I have a five cubic foot chest freezer converted into a kegerator. Since I set this up, I've had a standard regulator and one corny or sixth barrel sanke keg in there at a time. I'm planning to slowly upgrade to having 3-4 kegs total.

I'm wondering if it is horribly inconvenient (or even possible) to try to use a single body regulator with a gas manifold/distributor if you are trying to dispense from 1-2 kegs while force carbonating another. Is it worthwhile to splurge on the nice dual-body regulator, or is that unnecessary?

Here is the [dual-body regulator](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/double-gas-regulator.html) I've been looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dual regulator is only necessary if you want beers at different carb levels. For the most part though I have never needed that set up.  I have a simple single regulator and a 4 point manifold.  Each point has its own on off switch.  So when I want to dispense beer they are all open, but if I am carbing up a new beer, I close down three of them and carb the other beer.  If I need to serve switch off the one and open up the other.  In general its good practice to not leave the kegs continuously hooked up to gas in case of a leak.  So you always have a gas line free for carbing.

Answer (score 2):

Force carbonating is the main reason you'd want to have a dual regulator, but I'd rather have two co2 tanks, each with their own regulator.  I use one tank for force carbonating 1-2 kegs, and I have another tank for serving 3 kegs. I prefer this set up because when one tank is empty, I can easily switch over to the other tank.  No need to suffer without beer for a day until I fill the empty tank.

Comment: My kegs usually have enough pressure to push beer out without needing to be hooked up constantly.

Comment: wow, really? what PSI to you pressurize at? When my co2 tank dies, I can get a couple of pints out, but then I need to replace the tank.

Comment: 12-15psi, usually.  My fridge hasn't been converted, though, so I'm still using a cobra tap and squatting down to the level of the beer or lower to fill my glasses.

Comment: ahh ok that makes sense.  My taps are all above the keg.